# Understanding KVM Bridges

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, stp

I've spent a few days learning and playing with KVM.  I understand a Bridge is like a virtual unmanaged switch.  I looked at a few install guides (i.e. https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-kvm-qemu-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html).  The initial setup (with a single working VM I can ssh into from host. From the host I can do this (in terms of bridges/networks)

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.000acd288913       no              enp1s2
virbr0          8000.5254009da072       yes             virbr0-nic

$ sudo virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes
```

So if I understand correctly I have 2 bridges (virtual switches), one (br0) connected to enp1s2 (my main server interface connected to the host) and virbr0 connected to virbr0-nic (internal KVM network?).

So my question is how is this wired and why is it wired like this. What other commands are there to help me work this out?   Something like VM->virbr0->br0->host.

I'm also a little confused about Spanning Tree Protocol, what exactly it does and how KVM needs/uses it.  All the descriptions I have read confuse my poor little brain.

Lastly with this setup (if the firewall is set up to allow port 22) if I set up the VM with a Public IP would I be able to ssh into the VM from the internet.  I.e. I only need to set up the public IP on the VM (not the host) and the bridge routers it to from internet to VM (via the host) without setting up any specific routings/forwards ....

Ben

Comment: I think the KVM would need to use the br0 instead of VM->virbr0)>br0, but I am also stuck with configuration issues. Looking forward to an answer to this question.